# Regex to match all of symbols but except a word

Tags: javascript, regex

How do regex to match all of symbols but except a word?

Need find all symbols except a word.

`(.*)` - It find all symbols.

`[^v]` - It find all symbols except letter `v`

But do how **find all symbols except a word**?

Solution (writed below):

```
((?:(?!here any word for block)[\s\S])*?)
```

or

`((?:(?!here any word for block).)*?)`

`((?:(?!video)[\s\S])*?)`

---

I want to find all except `|end|` and replace all except `|end|.

I try:

Need all except `|end|`

```js
var str = '|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|';
// May be:
//var str = '|end| |video| |water| |sun| |cloud|';
//var str = '|cloud| |video| |water| |sun| |end|';

str.replace(/\|((?!end|end$).*?)\|/gm, test_fun2);

function test_fun2(match, p1, offset, str_full) {
  console.log("--------------");
  p1 = "["+p1+"]";
  console.log(p1);
  console.log("--------------");
  return p1;
}
```

Output console log:

```
--------------
[video]
--------------
--------------

--------------
--------------

--------------
--------------

--------------
```

Example what need:

Any symbols except `[video](`

**input** - `'[video](text-1 *******any symbols except: "[video](" ******* [video](text-2  any symbols) [video](text-3 any symbols) [video](text-4 any symbols) [video](text-5 any symbols)'`

**output** - `<div>text-1 *******any symbols except: "[video](" *******</div> <div>text-2  any symbols</div><div>text-3 any symbols</div><div>text-4 any symbols</div><div>text-5 any symbols</div>`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191343/discussion-on-question-by---regex-to-match-all-of-symbols-but-ex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Scenario 1

Use the [best trick ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick):

> One key to this technique, a key to which I'll return several times, is that we completely disregard the overall matches returned by the regex engine: that's the trash bin. Instead, we inspect the Group 1 matches, which, when set, contain what we are looking for.

**Solution:**

```
s = s.replace(/\|end\||\|([^|]*)\|/g, function ($0, $1) { 
    return $1 ? "[" + $1 + "]" : $0; 
});
```

**Details**

- `\|end\|` - `|end|` is matched
- `|` - or
- `\|([^|]*)\|` - `|` is matched, any 0+ chars other than `|` are captured into Group 1, and then `|` is matched.

If Group 1 matched (`$1 ?`) the replacement occurs, else, `$0`, the whole match, is returned back to the result.

JS test:

```js
console.log(
   "|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|".replace(/\|end\||\|([^|]*)\|/g, function ($0, $1) { 
        return $1 ? "[" + $1 + "]" : $0; 
    })
)
```

## Scenario 2

Use

```
.replace(/\[(?!end])[^\]]*]\(((?:(?!\[video]\()[\s\S])*?)\)/g, '<div>$1</div>')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xKRisK/2)

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?!end])` - no `end]` allowed right after the current position
- `[^\]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `((?:(?!\[video])[\s\S])*?)` - Group 1 that captures any char (`[\s\S]`), 0 or more occurrences, but as few as possible (`*?`) that does not start a `[video](` char sequence
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: That is a really neat trick. I think you have a typo in the "Solution" that is fixed in the "JS test": `return $1 : "[" + $1 + "]" : $0; ` should have a `?` rather than a `:` after the first `$1`, right?

Comment: @MassPikeMike Looks like I copied it from the comment and forgot to fix after I noticed this bug in the code, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is better done in multiple steps. Also, if you're matching stuff, you should use `match`.

```
var str = '|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|';
var matches = str.match(/\|.*?\|/g);

// strip pipe characters...
matches = matches.map(m=>m.slice(1,-1));

// filter out unwanted words
matches = matches.filter(m=>!['end'].includes(m));
           // this allows you to add more filter words easily
           // if you'll only ever need "end", just do (m=>m!='end')

console.log(matches); // ["video","water","sun","cloud"]
```

Notice how this is a lot easier to understand what's going on, and also much easier to maintain and change in future as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for try help me!  I update my question. Me need output string not array. And if  write `|video |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|` 
 will be `["video ", " ", " ", " "]`

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Here is what you need to do with regex:

```js
var str = '|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|';

console.log(str.replace(/(?!\|end\|)\|(\S*?)\|/gm, test_fun2));

function test_fun2(match, p1, offset, str_full) {
  return "["+p1+"]";
}
```

And an explanation of what was wrong - you had your negative-lookahead placed *after* the `|` character. That means that the matching engine would do the following:

1. Match `|video|` because the pattern works with it
2. Grab the next `|`
3. Find that the next text is `end` which is in the negative lookahead and drop it.
4. Grab the `|` *immediately after* `end`
5. grab the space and the next `|` character, since this passes the negative lookahead and also works with `.*?`
6. continue grabbing the intermediate `| |` sequences because the `|` in the *beginning* of the word was consumed by the previous match.

So you end up matching the following things

```
var str = '|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|';
           ^^^^^^^     ^^^     ^^^   ^^^
|video| ______|         |       |     |
| | ____________________|       |     |
| | ____________________________|     |
| | __________________________________|
```

All because the `|end` match was dropped.

You can see this if you print out the matches

```js
var str = '|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|';

str.replace(/\|((?!end|end$).*?)\|/gm, test_fun2);

function test_fun2(match, p1, offset, str_full) {
  console.log(match, p1, offset);
}
```

You will see that the second, third, and fourth `match` is `| |` the captured item `p1` is  - a blank space (not very well displayed, but there) and the offset they were found were `12`, `20`, `26`

```
|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|
01234567890123456789012345678901234
            ^       ^     ^
12 _________|       |     |
20 _________________|     |
26 _______________________|
```

The change I made was to instead look for explicitly the `|end|` pattern in a negative lookahead and also to only match non-whitespace characters, so you don't grab `| |` again.

Also worth noting that you can move your filtering logic to the replacement callback instead, instead of the regex. This simplifies the regex but makes your replacement more complex. Still, it's a fair tradeoff, as code is usually easier to maintain if you have more complex conditions:

```js
var str = '|video| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|';

//capturing word characters - an alternative to "non-whitespace"
console.log(str.replace(/\|(\w*)\|/gm, test_fun2)); 

function test_fun2(match, p1, offset, str_full) {
  if (p1 === 'end') {
    return match;
  } else {
    return "[" + p1 + "]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you vary much for try help me! But if writed `|video+| |end| |water| |sun| |cloud|` will result `|video+| |end| [water] [sun] [cloud]`. I updated my the question, look please.